# How to pass parameters for method call in controller from gsp?

Tags: grails, gsp

I am calling a method located in the controller from my gsp file. The method in question has a parameter that need be filled.

The following is currently how I have it and does not work.

```
<g:each in="${msdsLinkList}" status="i" var="msdsLink">
  <div id="msdsBox${i}" class="msdsBox">
    <g:link class="word-button" action="exportAttachment(msdsLink${i})"></g:link>
  </div>
</g:each>
```

How can I pass msdsLink${i} in to the exportAttachment method?

Comment: To give you a more accurate answer. Could you share an example of the contents of msdsLinkList?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to elixir's answer, you can use `params` in your `g:link` tag:

```
<g:each in="${msdsLinkList}" status="i" var="msdsLink">
  <div id="msdsBox${i}" class="msdsBox">
    <g:link class="word-button" action="exportAttachment" id="${msdsLink.id}"
            params="[foo: 'bar', bar: 'foo', value: msdsLink.value]"></g:link>
  </div>
</g:each>
```

In your controller's method, you can simply use the `params` map :

```
params.id
params.foo
params.bar
params.value
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<g:each in="${msdsLinkList}" status="i" var="msdsLink">
  <div id="msdsBox${i}" class="msdsBox">
    <g:link class="word-button" action="exportAttachment" id="${msdsLink.id}"></g:link>
  </div>
</g:each>
```

In your controller, you can retrieve the passed in value as

```
params.id
```